# In witr, can you read a dua other than Dua qunoot?

Tags: quran, salat

Do you have to read dua qunoot in witr or are there any other duas you can read? 
My grandmother has told me that you can recite any dua, where you are asking Allah for help but I have also heard that it is wajib to read dua qunoot in witr.

I usually read 'Rabbi, ighfir li'. Is this Ok?

Comment: AFAIK you can read any dua, even multiple dua in witr prayer... qunoot dua is prefered...

Answer (score 5):

Any Dua should do it.

**Al-Nawawi** said: *`It should be noted that Qunoot do not have a prayer on the preferred point Any du'aa as Qunoot even recites a verse or verses from the Koran that include a supplication as Qunoot, but the best is mentioned in the Sunnah...`*

According to some scholars, you can also read any Dua in your native language - not necessarily Arabic - in qunoot of every prayer.

Sources: [Islam Way](http://akhawat.islamway.net/forum/index.php?showtopic=182678) and [Islam QA](http://www.islam-qa.com/ar/ref/9061)

Comment: Nice answer, may I inquire where you got it? name of the book, site address, etc.

Comment: Here the link to a more complete answer if you read arabic ==> http://akhawat.islamway.net/forum/index.php?showtopic=182678 the question was about a lady who can't memorize Du'a al qunoot

Comment: yes I can read Arabic, thank you for the link.  Here users are to add citations to their answers to back it up, it wouldn't matter what language as long as it is cited. I will add it to your answer for you.