# Which one is Qunut?

Tags: salat, dua, witr

Which one is the ‘Qunut’ prayed in ‘Witr’? I found the following two in the various place,

This is the one I use in the ‘Witr’

> اَللَّهُمَّ إنا نَسْتَعِينُكَ وَنَسْتَغْفِرُكَ وَنُؤْمِنُ بِكَ وَنَتَوَكَّلُ عَلَيْكَ وَنُثْنِئْ عَلَيْكَ الخَيْرَ وَنَشْكُرُكَ وَلَا نَكْفُرُكَ وَنَخْلَعُ وَنَتْرُكُ مَنْ ئَّفْجُرُكَ
>   اَللَّهُمَّ إِيَّاكَ نَعْبُدُ وَلَكَ نُصَلِّئ وَنَسْجُدُ وَإِلَيْكَ نَسْعأئ وَنَحْفِدُ وَنَرْجُو رَحْمَتَكَ وَنَخْشآئ عَذَابَكَ إِنَّ عَذَابَكَ بِالكُفَّارِ مُلْحَقٌ

This one I saw [in this video](https://youtu.be/a2-nTZiDQSg),

> اَللّهُمَّ اهْدِنِىْ فِيْمَنْ هَدَيْتَ وَعَافِنِى فِيْمَنْ عَافَيْتَ وَتَوَلَّنِىْ فِيْمَنْ تَوَلَّيْتَ وَبَارِكْ لِىْ فِيْمَا اَعْطَيْتَ وَقِنِيْ شَرَّمَا قََضَيْتَ، فَاِ نَّكَ تَقْضِىْ وَلاَ يُقْضَى عَلَيْكَ وَاِ نَّهُ لاَ يَذِلُّ مَنْ وَالَيْتَ وَلاَ يَعِزُّ مَنْ عَادَيْتَ تَبَارَكْتَ رَبَّنَا وَتَعَالَيْتَ فَلَكَ الْحَمْدُ عَلَى مَا قَضَيْتَ وَاَسْتَغْفِرُكَ وَاَتُوْبُ اِلَيْكَ وَصَلَّى اللهُ عَلَى سَيِّدَنَا مُحَمَّدٍ النَّبِيِّ اْلاُمِّيِّ وَعَلَى آلِهِ وَصَحْبِهِ وَسَلَّمَ

Comment: There's no "which one" both are accepted wordings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the matter of qunoot there are many different views on when (which prayer and whether it has to be done before or after ruku' and whether it is allowed to initiate it by takbeer) it is performed, whether it is mandoob, recommended or sunnah and which wording is used, but be aware that one isn't limited to the proposed wordings.
The shafi'i school of fiqh basically only uses the second wording while both the hanafis and malkis use the first one. But while the Hanafis perform it before ruku' in Witr. The malikis consider it as mandoob and would even accept performing it after ruku' in the second raka'a of the sobh (fard) prayer.

See also:

- [Reference of Qunoot Nazila of Umar (RA)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/49617/13438)
- [Is reciting qunoot mandatory in fajr salat?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/14941/13438)
- [In witr, can you read a dua other than Dua qunoot?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5878/13438)
- [What is Dua Qunut and when should we recite it in the Prayer/Salat?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/7380/13438)
- [What is the source of this dua read in Witr prayer?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5585/13438)

Answer (score 0):

Asalam ALikum !
 The First one you mentioned is `Dua e Qanoot`; which should be recited in **Vitr**

https://www.islamicfinder.org/duas/masnoon/dua-e-qunoot-recited-in-witr-prayer/

the 2nd one is `Qanoot e Nazila` which is prayed When the Muslims Community is afflicted with some hardship then `Qunoot-E-Naazilah` should be recited in the Fajr Salaat.

check this for sorting any confussion

http://www.islaam.org/Qunoot/qunoot-e-nazilah.htm

Comment: Both are known as qunoot an-Nazilah as performing qunoot by our prophet actually is related to Nawazil he isn't known to have performed it on regular basis. .